# Golang Lambda function on AWS API Gateway not returning PDF

Tags: go, pdf, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am using a Golang serverless lambda function behind API Gateway. The API Gateway is set to proxy ANY to the Lamdba function.

It functions as a REST API returning JSON to a front end. We needed to generate a PDF on one of the routes, and return it. This is functioning perfectly fine when running Golang HTTP Server locally, but failing on AWS.

I have read about and implemented binary data on API gateway already.The head scratcher here is as follows:

- No binary data types enabled on API GW - Rest api returning JSON
  works, PDF returns but is corrupted.
- Enable "application/pdf" binary data type - Rest api returning JSON
  works, PDF returns but is corrupted.
- Enable "*/*" binary data type - API GW returns 500 on normal preflight
  OPTIONS (CORS) request and fails, PDF works perfectly.

If I look at the payloads returned on these requests, local returns data beginning with JVBER and works. API Gateway without binary data types returns payload that is base64 encoded that when decoded also appears to be a PDF beginning with JVBER but is truncated and corrupt.

Abbreviated Golang function:

```
"github.com/jung-kurt/gofpdf"

 func Print(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
            pdf := gofpdf.New("P", "mm", "A4", "")
            pdf.AddPage()
    
            pdf.SetFont("Arial", "B", 16)
            pdf.SetXY(10, 5)
            pdf.Cell(30, 15, "Stack Overflow")
    
            //Set header
            w.Header().Set("Content-type", "application/pdf")
            w.Header().Set("content-disposition", "inline")
            pdf.Output(w)
    }
```

CORS is implemented as follows:

```
cors := cors.New(cors.Options{
    AllowedOrigins:   []string{"*.blah.net"},
    AllowedMethods:   []string{http.MethodGet, http.MethodPost, http.MethodPut, http.MethodOptions, http.MethodDelete},
    AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token", "Set-Cookie"},
    AllowCredentials: true,
    MaxAge:           1800,
})
r.Use(cors.Handler)
```

When binary data types is set to "*/*" the cors request fails in the logs as follows:

```
Method request body before transformations: [Binary Data]

Execution failed due to configuration error: Unable to transform response
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: how about encoding?  Headers look okay.  Can you send a static string PDF back?

Comment: Thanks for your questions and Interest Frank. Unfortunately this became a time blocker for us, and I ended up writing the file to S3 and returning the link which took me about 5 mins. If i have some time I will revisit at a later stage.

Comment: Case 2 usually works. Confirm that your response body is base64 encoded and include isBase64Encoded set to true in your response